# No VirtualBox.so file while running VBox

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

I am trying to run HaikuOS in VirtualBox, but when I try to run it via Synapse, nothing happens and when I try to run it via the Terminal, I get the following error:

`supR3HardenedMainGetTrustedMain: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox.so",) failed: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

I have tried installing from Terminal, a .deb package from Oracle, and the Synaptic package manager. Are there any ways to fix it?

Comment: I too have the same problem. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might need to install a package that provides libGL.so.1. The following might help guide you to the correct package:

[Ubuntu package contents search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&arch=i386&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libGL.so.1)

Comment: None of those packages mention virtualbox, not sure which one to install?

Comment: @SelbyRowley-Cannon Some of them appear to be graphics-card specific... the Nvidia ones for Nvidia cards, fglrx for AMD-based graphics. libgl1-mesa-glx looks somewhat generic... maybe try that one first?

Comment: OK,  that one hasn't worked, any other ideas, anyone?

Comment: @SelbyRowley-Cannon Is the error exactly the same? Specifically, is it still complaining about libGL.so.1?

Comment: Yes, it is complaining about libGL.so.1, do you know how to fix it?